# Draw Triangle Wave

Tags: java

I have a little code that draws a triangle wave:

```
     package work3;




    import javafx.application.Application;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.lang.Math;
    import javax.swing.*;


    public class work2 extends JFrame implements ActionListener

{
    public boolean check;
    public boolean check2;
    public boolean check3;
    JButton button1;
    JButton button2;
    JButton button3;
    JLabel label;
    JPanel panel;

    //sinus
    int xBase   = 0;
    int top     = 100;
    static int ampli  = 100;
    int xAxis   = 36000;       
    int yBase   = top + ampli;
    int x, y;

    //rechteck
    static int ampy=300;
     int ampx=100;

     static int abcd ;
    static int freq;

    //dreieck
     int amp=100;





    public work2(){
        this.setTitle("ROFLELMAO");
        this.setSize(800, 400);
        panel = new JPanel();

        // Leeres JLabel-Objekt wird erzeugt
        label = new JLabel();

        //Drei Buttons werden erstellt
        button1 = new JButton("Button 1");
        button2 = new JButton ("Button 2");
        button3 = new JButton ("Button 3");

        //Buttons werden dem Listener zugeordnet
        button1.addActionListener(this);
        button2.addActionListener(this);
        button3.addActionListener(this);

        //Buttons werden dem JPanel hinzugefügt
        panel.add(button1);
        panel.add(button2);
        panel.add(button3);

        //JLabel wird dem Panel hinzugefügt
        panel.add(label);
        this.add(panel);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        work2 bl = new work2();
        bl.setVisible(true);

    }




    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent ae){

        if(ae.getSource() == this.button1){

            check=true;
            repaint();


        }
        else if(ae.getSource() == this.button2){
            check2=true;     
             repaint();
        }
        else if (ae.getSource() == this.button3){
            check3=true; 
             repaint();
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){


        if(check==true){
            changevalue();
            //koordinatensystem

             g.drawLine( xBase, yBase, xBase + xAxis, yBase );

             g.setColor( Color.red );
             for( int i=0; i < xAxis; i++ ){
                 x = xBase + i;
                 y = (int)( yBase - Math.sin( Math.toRadians(i) ) * ampli );
                 g.drawLine( x, y, x, y );
             }
             }

        if(check2==true){
            changevalue2();

            g.drawLine( xBase, yBase, xBase + xAxis, yBase );
            g.setColor( Color.blue );


            boolean up = true;
//          ampx= 50;
            while (x <= 1000) {

                if (x > 0 && x % freq == 0) { //50 ist frequenz
                    up = !up;

                    g.drawLine(0 + x, up ? ampx : ampy + y, 0 + x, up ? ampy : ampx + y);
                }
                else {
                    if (up) {
                        g.drawLine(0 + x, ampx + y, 0 + x, y + ampx);
                    }                   
                    else {
                        g.drawLine(0 + x, ampy + y, 0 + x, y + ampy);
                    }
                }
                x++;

            }






        }


             if(check3==true){
                 g.drawLine( xBase, yBase, xBase + xAxis, yBase );
                int x1=0; 
                int y1=200 ;
                int x2=150; 
                int y2=140;

                g.drawLine(x1,y1,x2,y2);

                for (int i=0; i<6; i++){
                x1=0+x2;
                y1=0+y2;

                x2=x2+150;
                y2=y2+amp;

                g.drawLine(x1,y1,x2,y2);

                x1=0+x2;
                y1=0+y2;

                x2=x2+150;
                y2=y2-amp;
                g.drawLine(x1,y1,x2,y2);

                }

             }



             }














    public static void changevalue(){
     System.out.println("amplitude:");
        Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
      ampli= (int) a.nextDouble();


}
    public static void changevalue2(){
         System.out.println("freq:");
        Scanner b = new Scanner(System.in);
       freq= (int) b.nextDouble();

       System.out.println("amplitude:");
        Scanner c = new Scanner(System.in);
         abcd= (int) b.nextDouble();

    }
    }
```

How could I improve this code?

Comment: Could you translate the following terms so non-German speakers can understand more easily? `aufgabe`, `andere`, `eubung`

Comment: @user1118321 in the future please do not ask users to translate code. See this meta post for the explanation of this policy: http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/3795/should-code-be-forcibly-translated-into-english

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for taking the time to translate your names! It makes it a little easier to understand what's going on.

## Naming

I think the biggest issue I see with this code is the naming of the classes, methods, and variables. For example, the class is named `work2`. What kind of work? How does it relate to `work1`? Is there a `work1`? This class doesn't inherit from it, so it's hard to know. Also, `work` is a very generic term. Most applications and classes perform some sort of work. I think a better class name would be something like `waveformDrawer` or `waveformDisplay` or something along those lines.

Any time you find your self naming variables `<something>1`, `<something>2`, `<something>3`, it's a good sign that you either need better naming, or you need to use an array. In this case, I think you just need better naming. What do `button1`, `button2`, and `button3` do? From reading the code, it looks like they draw a sine wave, a square wave, and a triangle wave? So why not name them something like `drawSineButton`, `drawSquareButton`, and `drawTriangleButton`? Or something similar. Likewise with the `check*` variables.

The variable `abcd` doesn't appear to serve any purpose. It's only used in a single method, so it could just be a local variable, but even there, it's value is set, then never used.

## Drawing waveforms

There's a better way to draw waveforms that allows you to perform the same operations for each type of waveform. Doing it that way will simplify your code.

A triangle wave can be calculated periodically as described in [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_wave#Definitions):

```
y(x) = |x mod 4 - 2 | - 1
```

Where 4 is the period (inverse of frequency). So in code, it would look something like this:

```
y = ampli * (Math.abs(fmod(x, 1.0 / freq) - 2.0) - 1.0);
```

Here, `fmod` is the floating point modulus function. I'm not sure where it's found in Java off the top of my head. (Note that the remainder operator `%` doesn't do the right thing with negative numbers in this case.)

You could then put that into a loop just like the sine example. And for a square wave, you can simply take the sign of a sine wave:

```
y = ampli * Math.copySign(Math.sin(x));
```

(Note that my Java is a bit rusty. It looks like the math functions are all part of a `Math` class, so you probably need `Math.sign(Math.sin())` etc. I might be confusing the Java and C names for the functions, but I think they're similar.)